# Calculated field with value from another table in Microsoft Access

Tags: mysql, ms-access, ms-access-2013, calculated-field

I have a calculated field in a table that needs to take the value from another table but in the expression generator window it doesn't allow me to choose values from other tables.
Then, I tried to create a form from the table, and put in the source control the function that I need but it triggers a `#Name?` Error in the form.

This is the code that I put in the source control (Iff function) :

```
=IIf([Stato]="Vendita";[Costo ivato 1 pezzo]+(([Costo ivato 1 pezzo]/100)*[Provv_Vendita]![Costo]);[Costo ivato 1 pezzo]+(([Costo ivato 1 pezzo]/100)*[Provv_Prevendita]![Costo]))
```

`[Stato]` and `[Costo ivato 1 pezzo]` are two fields that are in the same table (called `Prodotti`) that is structured like this:

```
Stato      Costo Ivato 1 pezzo

Vendita         10
Prevendita      20
```

The other table (called `Provvigioni`) is like

```
Tipo        Costo

Vendita       1,5
Prevendita    5
```

`Provv_Vendita` and `Provv_Prevendita` are two queries that select the values that I need and are structured like this

```
SELECT Provvigioni.Costo
FROM Provvigioni
WHERE Provvigioni.Tipo="Vendita";
```

Is there a way to take the field from the other table and use in a function on the first table?

Comment: There's quite a lot problems with this question. 1) In your IIF statement you've used semi colons (;) rather than commas (,). 2) You are probably getting a `#Name?` error on your form, because the fields you've referenced in your `IFF` statement don't exist on the form (i.e. you haven't given the form a Record Source that refers to a table/query containing those fields). 3) In the Provvigioni table you've said that `Vendita` has a `Costo` of "1,5"... is it meant to be this or is it 1.5? 4) Your `IIF` statement would be better suited to a query (see my answer below).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you're after here, but I thought it would be best to show you how to link your 2 tables in a query first..

Go to Create > Query Design:

[image]

Add both your tables (double-click them):

[image]

Then close the Show Table window; you should have your tables in the Query Designer now:

[image]

Click and drag from Stato to Tipo; this should create a join between these fields:

[image]

Double-click on all your fields in each table so that they will appear in the query:

[image]

In the next available field for your query, right-click in the "Field" box and select "Zoom":

[image]

Put your `IIF` statement in there; precede it with a field name and colon, like this for example:

[image]

...Note that I've tidied your `IFF` statement up a bit, so it now reads:

`MyCalculatedField: IIf([Stato]="Vendita",[Costo ivato 1 pezzo]+(([Costo ivato 1 pezzo]/100)*[Costo]),[Costo ivato 1 pezzo]+(([Costo ivato 1 pezzo]/100)*[Costo]))`

Click OK on the "Zoom" window. Click "Run" to see the result of your query:

[image]

Here's what the query results in (check your calculated field is what you expect it to be):

[image]

If you want the result of this query to populate data in a form then you should save the query...

[image]

...and name it something:

[image]

You can then go to Create > Form Design:

[image]

In the Property Sheet on the right-hand side, go to the "Data" tab and use the drop-down next to Record Source to select the query you just saved:

[image]

If you go to Design > Add Existing Fields, you should be able to bring in the fields from your Query for use in your Form (Double-click or drag them to make appear on your Form):

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Fabulous! The only criticism is that in my version access make me us the semicolons as separator for the function fields, I think it is a localization thing, I live in Italy. Thanks, anyway

Comment: ahh ok! didn't realise formulas change based on location :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a query.

Bring in the two tables and create a join between Stato and Tipo.

Now you can select [Costo] and [Costo Ivato 1 pezzo]