# Find duplicates in concatenate field / two tables

Tags: sql, ms-access, duplicates, concatenation

I'm just starting working with Access and I'm struggling with a concatenation issue.
I need to look for duplicates into a pair of values from fields of two different tables ("publinom" and "publiannee").
What I did is concatenate the two fields following this solution (using the zoom property in a query)
 [Calculated field with value from another table in Microsoft Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30053847/calculated-field-with-value-from-another-table-in-microsoft-access)

So the result looks like:

query design view: concatenate 2 fields from 2 tables
[image: query design view: concatenate 2 fields from 2 tables]

query datasheet view: concatenate 2 fields from 2 tables
[image: query datasheet view: concatenate 2 fields from 2 tables]

Now I need to loop into the "publiconcat" field to look for duplicates.

I tried to find duplicates with the query wizard, it returns an error message:

> "Your query does not include the specified expression 'Count(*)>1
>       And [publinom.nom] + " " + [publiannee.annee]=' as part of an
>       aggregate function"

Can someone tell me what's happening?

Comment: Question has nothing to do with VBA, this is SQL, so I edited tags. It is not necessary to concatenate fields to locate duplicate pairs. Also, `&` character is preferred for concatenation. Why is nom field in two tables? Post the SQL statement - switch query to SQLView and copy/paste string into your question.

Comment: Thank you for your comment: I figured out how to do it thanks to them. As you said, no need for concatenation to solve my problem: looking for duplicates pairs with SQL work fine!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. The conception was wrong; no need to concatenate and then, look for duplicates into the concatenated field, but just look for duplicates pairs with  this SQL code:

```
SELECT publinom.nom, publiannee.annee
FROM publinom INNER JOIN (publiauteur INNER JOIN publiannee ON publiauteur.IDPK = publiannee.IDpubliauteurFK) ON publinom.IDPK = publiauteur.IDpublinomFK
GROUP BY publinom.nom, publiannee.annee HAVING COUNT(*)=2
```